# Torsors for nonabelian groups and maps to contracted products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, stacks, torsors

$\newcommand\op{\mathrm{op}}$My question concerns torsors for a sheaf of groups $G$ that is *not* commutative, and left/right are messing me up. A left $G$-torsor is equivalent to a right $G^{\op}$-torsor, and vice versa, where $G^{\op}$ multiplies things backwards: $g \star h := h \cdot g$. I'm happy with an answer in full topos generality or for finite groups acting on schemes in the etale topology or anything in between, as long as the groups don't have to be abelian.

Let $P$ be a left $G$-torsor and let $G$ act on $X$ on the right. One can form the contracted product $X \wedge^G P = X \times P/(-\Delta, G)$ by modding out by the left antidiagonal action of $G$: $g . (x, p) := (x . g^{-1}, g . p)$.

The quotient $X \times P \to X \wedge^G P$ by the free antidiagonal action is a torsor. So a map from anything $T \to X \wedge^G P$ entails a $G$-torsor $Q \to T$ and an equivariant map $Q \to X \times P$. This equivariance entails an equivariant map $Q \to P$ and an *antiequivariant map* $\varphi: Q \to X$. That means
$$\varphi(g.q) = \varphi(q).g^{-1}.$$
Or, thinking of $X$ as a *left* $G^{\op}$-object, the map $Q \to X$ is equivariant for the inverse map $i : G \to G^{\op}$ sending $g \mapsto g$.

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967912/definition-of-equivariant-map-if-one-of-the-actions-is-a-right-action/967939#967939?s=7e00bc8ddf59466ba58f0a771bdd09b7) convinces me I've messed something up. If $G$ is abelian, $i$ is a group homomorphism and yields an equivalence between left and right that renders this point moot. Are there situations where $i$ still gives an equivalence between left and right torsors for nonabelian groups? E.g. [Abramovich-Graber-Vistoli](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40068158) talk about inverting the band of a gerbe (like a torsor) but only use the abelian case. I was under the impression that's the only time you can.

Is there such a thing as a stack quotient for antiequivariant maps like above? -- this would parameterize left $G$ torsors $Q$ together with a map $\varphi: Q \to X$ with $\varphi (g.q) = \varphi(q).g^{-1}$. I'm pretty sure the notion doesn't make sense.

I imagine this situation has been dealt with before -- a reference would be appreciated. I only care about $X \wedge^G P$ as a twisted form of $X$; I could use equivariant maps $\text{Hom}^G(P, X)$ and have $G$ act on $X$ on the left instead but I'm not sure it fixes the left/right problem. Is there any equivalent way of describing maps $T \to X \wedge^G P$ in terms of torsors with maps to $X, P$, i.e. in terms of maps to $[X/G]$?

Comment: I don't know what does it mean for a map to be equivariant for a map between groups which is not a homomorphism. On the other hand, I think $\varphi:Q\to X$ is equivariant for the group isomorphism $G\to G^{\mathrm{op}}$ that sends $g$ to $g^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you. I made a dumb mistake.